# Files lost during move & power failure

Tags: partitioning, data-recovery, ntfs, sd-card

I was moving (using the default Ubuntu file manager) some photos from my SD card (formated FAT32) to a NTFS drive on my computer when a power failure occured.

After that, I used the SD card in my camera, made some new pictures and then moved all the pictures from the card to another computer.

After starting the first computer, some 2 Gb of files where missing from my SD card, and the folder where I moved them was shown empty in Ubuntu. I checked & repaired the drive in Windows 7, this got me access to a couple of files from the ones I had lost.

Going back to Ubuntu, I tried using PhotoRec both on the SD card and NTFS drive, but with no luck - I did not recover the photos I was looking for, but only other photos.

At this time, the SD card should be almost empty (it only contains a .trash folder with about 200 mb of files). Checking it properties, it shows around 2 Gb (the same size as my lost files) as used.

Any ideas?

Comment: Installed _scalpel_ - after some googleing, I modified the config file to recover jpg files, then ran the software. The result: some 10.000 jpg files of around 100kb, unusable - my photos where about 4 Mb to 6 Mb each. Other ideas?

Comment: Karel, I used the command: **scalpel /dev/sd-card-drive -o /destination/drive** Also, I removed the comment sign (#) from the jpeg line in the scalpel config file. If there is something else I should have done, le me know. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Does the camera (by itself) allow you to see any images? I agree with karel you probably haven't lost them, just hidden (do you have file permission to rwx?) Also try a different file-manager like PCManFM to see if it is a software problem. Do any other computer's show anything..is your USB locked?

Comment: The camera does not show any pictures, I have opened the card in both Ubuntu (with default file manager and Krusader) and Windows (Win Explorer + Windows Commander) and it only contains a .Trash folder. The card is formated FAT32, permissions are not an issue.

Comment: I reread your post, so you 'moved' the files, you didn't 'copy' the files...this right here means you will not have the ones that were successfully moved, on the original card where they were kept. So try doing a search for all of your photo files. Here is a good reference to use. [Command 'find'](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FindingFiles)

Comment: The card **should** be empty - first I moved some files (the ones I need), made a couple of new photos, than moved all the files from the card. Still, the drive properties show I have some 2 Gb of data on it (nowhere to be found). Using several recovery programs I found a lot of pictures, even some from 2 months ago, but cannot find the files I want.